# How do I configure Django / Nginx to serve later-created Media files?

Tags: django, nginx, django-views, yaml, nginx-config

In my views.py, I have a function that creates a `.wav` file (speech synthesis of user-created input). This file is then stored in my media folder:

(views.py):

```py
filepath = synthesize_speech(text, language)

if filepath:
    # Provide a URL to access the audio file
    audio_url = request.build_absolute_uri(settings.MEDIA_URL + filepath)
    return JsonResponse({'audio_url': audio_url})
```

(settings.py):

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

This works together with (urls.py) really well in DEBUG:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # other URL patterns...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

---

But in production, using Nginx, this does not work anymore.

My Nginx config looks like this (nginx.conf):

```bash
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/media/;
    }
}
```

Also, I have added a volume (docker-compose.yml):

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  ...

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    depends_on:
      - web

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

(Please note, I have read, that it is not ideal to have the media folder within the Django project, but that is for now the easiest way for me to switch between dev and prod).

I tried adding `autoindex on` to the Nginx config. It showed an empty folder, even though it should've shown the audio files the user created with their input and button presses.

The overall expected behavior would be for Nginx to serve the newly by the user created `.wav` instead of outputting a 404 error.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out...but big question is why are you storing production files locally? All this takes is a server issue that requires moving to a new one, and you've lost data. Best practice, in my opinion, is to utilize cloud file storage. Then if your server blows up, you simply create a new one, pull code from git, then compose up and all is the same as your media is stored externally. Cloud Storage for this should be relatively inexpensive depending on who you use, but any expense for that is mitigated by the potential of losing client data

Comment: @ViaTech that is a actually a good question. I don't _really_ need persistent storage so I thought this way it is easier for me to maintain (and somewhat cheaper, but that is not the issue here). For now, I only store the user-created `.wav` file for only 1 day until I have another cron-job to delete the file.

Do you recommend using cloud file storage for staticfiles? Is it easy to maintain / update them? The issue I am having that I have to remove the whole Nginx static volume in order to auto-create a new one when running `docker-compose up --build -d` which I figure is not optimal...

Comment: Yes, in your instance there is still the issue of losing data, static files in production should nearly always be served from the cloud. I would look into DigitalOcean Spaces it is very inexpensive and you can use Djangos file backend with S3 to connect very easily.

Comment: @ViaTech alright, thank you very much. I will look into this :D

I already host on Digitalocean, so I think that it will be even easier to connect everything. I'll need to move everything to AWS by october because then my DO nonprofit credits are running out but thats a "future-me" problem lol

Comment: I suggest you see this page: https://github.com/MrMrProgrammer/Deploy-Django-project

Answer (score 0):

The issue had to do with my `docker-compose.yml` file.

Since I have not configured the same volume for the Django application ("web") and nginx, files were only stored in the web container but not on Nginx.

Solution (docker-compose.yml):

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: ...
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media #<--- HERE
    depends_on:
      - redis

  ...

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    depends_on:
      - web

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```